# JavaScript error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName'

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am using the following jQuery to get the field value from a Display Form in SharePoint 2013 so I can pass the value along in a URL.

```
var itemID = $('h3:contains("My ID")').closest('td').next('td').text();
```

It is working perfectly, but I am getting an error when I inspect the action:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference
>   File: sp.ui.dialog.js, Line: 2, Column: 22380

This contradicts what is actually occurring, since the code executes. I am running IE11 in IE10 compatibility mode.

Comment: I expect that `closest` calls getElementsByTagName, and that the value returned by $('h3:contains("My ID")') is undefined, however, it could also be that the first `closest` itself failed to retrieve a result.
Seems that you're experiencing a heisenbug effect. Are there any other ways you can inspect it?

Comment: Thank you for the insight. What is odd is that it is traversing and getting value. I may test this in another browser to see if it is IE.

Comment: I just tested it in chrome and received the same error, but everything is functioning perfectly.

Comment: If you are still experiencing this problem, I would advice you to add temporary logging to the code: assign each 'part' of the thing you're `.`ing though to a variable and log it using `console.log`
ex. `var contains = $('h3:contains("My ID")');
console.log(contains);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when the URL being passed to the modal function was invalid.  In my case, I has a dynamic URL containing a variable named itemID.  I got the error whenever itemID was undefined.

I wish I could elaborate further but all I can comment on is my own observations at this point.